# Turning drop and drag capability back on before close of workbook

Tags: excel, vba, drag-and-drop

I have a workbook that requires no drag and drop to occur. I turned off the drag and drop function on open of workbook by

```
Private sub Workbook_open()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

I am trying to turn it back on before close with

```
Private sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub
```

It is not working.

Comment: If you turn Drag 'n Drop off while it's open, then I don't understand the use of turn it back on just before closing. You cannot Drag 'n drop while it's closed and when you open it then it gets turned back off again anyway. How do you know that you code doesn't work? Or (in other words): how can you even verify if Drag 'n Drop is turned on while the file is closed? Or am I completely off topic?

Comment: The drag and drop function is an for the application not just the one workbook. If I turn it off when opening the workbook the functionality is then turned off for all workbooks and will not be turned back on until you go into Tools > options and re-tick the relevant box. I just want to turn it off to stop people stuffing up formulae while using one specific workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I stumbled across it and it remains unanswered. So, I'm answering it!

I've included in this code a disable for copy and paste functions as well. You can remove these if you only want to disable drag and drop. Stick this in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
'use if statement here if you want to situationally keep ribbon
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
'Else
'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
'use if statement here if you want to situationally keep ribbon
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
'Else
'Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
'End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This way, only the workbook with this code in will be disabled. You will be able to drag and drop, copy and paste, etc. on any other workbook even whilst this workbook is open.

If you want to temporarily enable drag and drop, copy and paste, etc. on your workbook for yourself, you can keep this code in a separate module and run it whenever you need it:

```
Sub Enable_CopyPaste()

'Run this sub when you need to access copy/paste tools

Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.OnKey "^v"
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}"
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}"
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"

End Sub
```

I hope you find this helpful even though you posted the question nearly three years ago!

Comment: Changed "close" to "before close" else it will only work whilst another workbook is open when the primary one is being closed.